# The Dihedral group $D_1$ is non-abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, dihedral-groups

Same as above.  I'm trying to show that for any n being odd, $D_n$ has exactly n elements of order 2 where $D_n$ is non-abelian. I know that for $n\ge3$ this is true, but what about for $n=1$.

Comment: $D_1$ is a group of order $2$, hence must be abelian.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your group theory question.
The dihedral group $D n$ has 2*n elements.
There is only one group with two elements.
So D1 is isomorphic to the group with 2 elements.
That group is like odd and even numbers with addition.
The even numbers are the identity element.
Here is the Cayley table - e for even and o for odd.

$+$ |  e  o
_____
e |  e  o
o |  o  e

Regards,
Matt

Comment: well does a non-abelian group with 1 element of order 2 exist? no right?

Comment: Yes: The quaternion group.

Comment: No, @Nishant what is the order of $-i$

Comment: The order of $-i$ is $4$.